# Python tkinter Library Not Installing properly

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, pip

I am trying to install Tkinter for PyDictionary which has installed fine, but Tkinter has not.

```
pip install tkinter
```

But this error has arisen:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
```

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

Anyone know any possible ways of fixing it? I downloaded python from python.org and I am coding on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: `tkinter` is part of python's standard libraries. So it should automatically be installed

Comment: I am having 9+ errors, though as such: {
Import "pyDictionary" could not be resolved }

Comment: just like @TheLizzard said tkinter is already a standard library, you can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: @AaronHannaway In a new python file (make sure you don't name it `tkinter.py`) write `import tkinter` and tell me if there is an error. There shouldn't be any errors

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip. It's simply not possible.